# How to quickly build module in Android Project?

Tags: android, makefile

Suppose I have an Android Project, and already compiled.
If I add an `printk` in kernel, and recompile `make bootimage`, it should be done quickly.

But Android Build System will still read bunch of makefiles, is there any way to skip this and just start compiling?

Comment: Do you work on AOSP? Which command you use that read a lot of makefiles?

Comment: @Daniel It's just `make bootimage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the same hack as here:
https://github.com/realdmitchell/condor-vendor-cm/blob/master/bootimage/Android.mk

This should allow you to use `mmm make <path to bootimage dir>` without parse all the makefiles in the tree